# How can I return a specific object from a generic function?

Tags: typescript

Consider this generic function:

```
  public getData<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(url);
  }
```

How can I return a **hardcoded mock object array** in order to test the function (for example because the remote API has not been implemented yet)?

I would like to return this:

```
return of([{id: 1, value: 'test1'}, {id: 2, value: 'test2'}]);
```

but I am getting this error:

> TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ id: number; value: string; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.   Type '{ id: number; value: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.     'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: number; value: string; }[]'.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return of([{id: 1, value: 'test1'}, {id: 2, value: 'test2'}] as unknown T);
```

Does the trick. Also `as any as T` should work as far as I know.

Comment: This does not work. However, this does: `return of([{ id: 1, value: 'test1' }, { id: 2, value: 'test2' }] as unknown as T);`

Comment: mmm that makes sense. I tried a really basic setup without importing `Observable` so it may need. Will change the answer.

Comment: 'any' works too (now that I think about it, of course it does ). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this by defining type in TS :
```

```
type ET = {
      id: number;
      value: string;
    };


getData(): Observable<ET[]> {
    return of([
      { id: 1, value: "test1" },
      { id: 2, value: "test2" },
    ]);
  }
```